# Replace \n(new line) with space in bash

Tags: bash, sed, tr

I am reading some sql queries into a variable from db and it contains new line character (\n). I want to replace \n (new line) with space. I tried solutions provided on internet but was unsuccessful to achieve what I want. Here is what tried :

```
strr="my\nname\nis\nxxxx";
nw_strr=`echo $strr | tr '\n' ' '`;
echo $nw_strr;
```

my desired output is "my name is xxxx" but what I am getting is "my\nname\nis\nxxxx". I also tried other solution provided at internet, but no luck:

```
nw_strr=`echo $strr | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'`;
```

Am I doing something wong?

Comment: For starters, as written `$strr` doesn't contain newlines, it contains literal backslash-N sequences. Try `strr=$'my\nname\nis\nxxxx'` to get proper newlines.

Comment: See also: [Unix & Linux: Using `sed` to convert newlines into spaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26788/114401)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With bash:

Replace all newlines with a space:

```
nw_strr="${strr//$'\n'/ }"
```

Replace all strings `\n` with a space:

```
nw_strr="${strr//\\n/ }"
```

Comment: Works for me, but as John Kugelman mentions in his comment above, this must be tested with `$strr` containing an actual newline. For example `strr=$'my\nname\nis\nxxxx'`.

Comment: Second one works for me. I guess all `\n` come as string while reading from mysql.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using `pipes`, you can do:

```
string_with_spaces=$(echo "$string_with_newlines" | tr '\n' ' ')
```

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26798/320602).